# Область видимости переменных java script

Tags: jquery, javascript

Существует глобальная переменная *`var CurrentMonth = 0;`*
При первом выполнении ajax запроса берется значение этой переменной. При возврате успеха от аяк происходит следующее:

```
success: function(data) {
CurrentMonth = data.CurrentMonth; // возвратило 12
}
```

Теперь при следующем выполнении ajax - значение по-прежнему остается 0 для переменной *CurrentMonth*

Comment: Не верю)

Нужен полный пример скрипта.

Comment: Видимо где-то допущена логическая ошибка, слишком мало данных, что бы хоть что-то сказать конкретное. Хорошо бы пример увидеть.